# PHP Mail form showing blank responses

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a PHP mail form from a Template that sends the email to me, but it appears all the variables are blank.

```html
<?php
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $status = array(
  'type'=>'success',
  'message'=>'Email sent!'
 );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['yourname'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['youremail'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['yoursubject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['yourmessage'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'kylef33@gmail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die; 
?>
```

And here, the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1>
        Contact Form
    </h1>
    <p>
        Fill out the form to enquire directly and we will get back to you as soon as possible.
    </p>
    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="yourname" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="youremail" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="yourmessage" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="yoursubject" value="Enquiry"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But the resulting email is:

Name:

Email:

Subject:

Message:

With none of the responses. Where am I going wrong?

Edit:

If I set the variables manually in the php file the message comes through fine:

```html
    $name = 'John'; 
    $email = 'email@email.com; 
    $subject = 'Enquiry Form'; 
    $message = 'Message here.';
```

I think the php file isn't getting the variables from the form correctly. How do I fix this?

Comment: Echo `$body` and check whether you are getting values properly.

Comment: why are you using `@trim` and `@mail`? You shouldn't need to suppress errors in this kind of script, and you're losing valuable troubleshooting information.

Comment: Have you tried changing `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>` to `<input type="submit"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the header of the email. try to add this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nFrom: $noReplay\r\nReply-To: $noReplay\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

where `$noReplay` is the email address to show to the receiver and the header is sent as a last parameter in [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Hope this helps!
Keep on coding,
Ares.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't help. I'm still getting blank responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try By use simple code and Set Content-type: text/html in headers it may useful:

```
$name = $_POST['yourname']; 
$email = $_POST['youremail']; 
$subject = $_POST['yoursubject']; 
$message = $_POST['yourmessage']; 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'kylef33@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

//set the headers 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: <'.$email_from.'>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Still gives me a blank e-mail. I can't figure it out. Could it be a problem with the php on my server?